# Target latest version of EcmaScript with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsconfig

Is there a way to set your typescript build to compile to either the latest or the latest stable version of EcmaScript?

i.e. `tsc --target <get latest version>`

Or for a tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./built",
      "target": <latest>
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [ESNext](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target):

> The special ESNext value refers to the highest version your version of TypeScript supports. This setting should be used with caution, since it doesn’t mean the same thing between different TypeScript versions and can make upgrades less predictable.

Note that this does not use the highest version of EcmaScript that exists in the published standard, but the highest version of EcmaScript *that your TypeScript supports* - which makes sense. TS can't just *automatically* support new tweaks to EcmaScript without compiler changes to TypeScript.